# Integration broker - userID not authorized for GETWSDL

Tags: peoplesoft

I am trying to get web services working in PeopleSoft to access Component Interfaces.  I get the following error.  But the UserID has access to the Integration Brokers web services, including GETWSDL.  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Integration Broker > Integration Setup > Node to open Local Node.

Make sure the default user ID is valid and the account is not locked out.

Or just set to "Anonymous".